# powershell parsing special chars to cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm having trouble sending cmds from powershell 2.0 to netsh in cmd.

The wierd thing is that with one type of command to netsh it works

Example - this works:

```
$input1 = @"
netsh wlan connect name=Aaknet ssid=Aaknet interface="Trådløs netværksforbindelse"
"@
$OutputVariable = ($WifiOn | netsh) | Out-String
```

netsh runs the command without any problems, eventhough interface name contains the char å

But if I run this - Powershell parses the å as an ? to the netsh cmd

```
$ConnectMBN = @"

netsh mbn connect interface="Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse" connmode=name name=3

"@

$ConnectMBN | netsh
```

pws returns in console:

```
netsh>netsh>Decommand not found:    netsh mbn connect interface="Mobilbredb?ndsforbindelse" connmode=name name=3.
```

As you can see pws turns the å into ?

Can anybody help cause I'm confused!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated based on our dialog in the comments.

The following code is an edit, of your edit, of my suggestion :-)

```
    $Char =[Char]34
    $Name ="Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse"
    $Interface ="$Char$Name$Char"
    $Name2="3"
    $Opts = @("mbn","connect","interface=$Interface","connmode=name","name=$Name2");
    netsh $Opts
```

So, putting the parameters for `netsh` into the array `$Opts`, using `[char]34` to denote a double quote in the only parameter that needs it, interface.

Using double quotes rather than single quotes in the array items means that any variables therein are expanded so their contents are part of the parameter array.

Finally invoking netsh directly as you would on the command line, followed by the parameter array, `$Opts`.

As i say, i have no mobile broadband so I get error about `wwansvc` not running but if I enter `$Opts` afterwards to view the contents I see:

```
mbn
connect
interface="Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse"
connmode=name
name=3
```

EDIT: Try this (have tried using netsh wlan connect that I could test with, since I can't test mbn)...

```
    $Char =[Char]34
    $Name ="Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse"
    $Interface ="$Char$Name$Char"
    $Name2="3"
    $connect = ("netsh mbn connect interface=$Interface connmode=name name=$Name2");
    $connect
```

Comment: Sorry a little typo with the netsh in $ConnectMBN - but i still get the problem on a danish version of windows7 as soon as i pipe the $ConnectMBN to netsh - pws changes the "Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse" into "Mobilbredb?ndsforbindelse" - and netsh returns CMD not found (Since it can't find a NIC with that name) if i Don´t pipe it and just fires $ConnectMBN, the output (on screen) is correct, but the NIC doesn´t connect I just doesn´t get it.. HELP Was just chekcing and noticed that I´m only running PWS v1.0 on my client - could that be the problem?

Comment: As I dont run windows in a language other than english, a little harder to test this, but try running netsh in the following way:  `$Opts = @('mbn','connect','interface="Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse"','connmode=name','name=3'); netsh $Opts`

Comment: Hi Graham - Tried you example with $Opts - still no luck

Comment: - still no luck :(
 - still gets error - the following command wasn´t found - and no connection

Comment: PS version is: 
PSVersion 2.0 
PSCompatibleVersions{1.0,2.0}                                                                
BuildVersion 6.1.7601.17514
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.1 
WSManStackVersion 2.0
CLRVersion 4.0.30319.296
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1

Comment: just tested again - og some reason the " around Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse doesn´t show up when i get the error - like this:
Den følgende kommando blev ikke fundet(following cmd wasn´t found): mbn connect interface=Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse connmode=name name=3.

Comment: sad but true... still no luck
>> Running (connconnect4.ps1) Script...
>> Platform: 32Bit
Den følgende kommando blev ikke fundet: mbn connect interface=Mobilbredbåndsforbindelse connmode=name name=3.

>> Execution time: 00:00:02
>> Script Ended

By some strange reason Netsh throws the " away... I'll be jumping to bed by now - its 01.20 here in Denmark right now... But thanks so far - tomorrow I'll try on a fresly installed Powershell cause this makes NO sense WSE

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason - my domain admin had redirected my %HOMESHARE% to a networkdrive
- that resultet in all the errors cause PWS couldn´t find the netsh on the share

i did this instead:
        $AakHotWifiOn = @"

```
  wlan connect name="AAKHotspot" ssid="AAKHotspot" interface="Trådløs    netværksforbindelse"

   "@

Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName . -Path win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "netsh $AakHotWifiOn"
```

The same method worked with the netsh mbn cinnect issue

thanks to Graham for all the input :)

Comment: glad you've gotten to the bottom of it, glad I could help in some way :-)